# How to setup IPv6 with docker-compose

Tags: docker, ipv6, docker-compose

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 on DigitalOcean, with IPv6 turned on:

```
PUBLIC IPV6 ADDRESS:
xxxx:xxxx:2:d0::216f:3001
PUBLIC IPV6 GATEWAY:
xxxx:xxxx:2:d0::1
CONFIGURABLE ADDRESS RANGE:
xxxx:xxxx:2:d0::216f:3000 - xxxx:xxxx:2:d0::216f:300f
```

According to this page: https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/ipv6/#docker-ipv6-cluster

Is it correct to put the 16 IPv6 addresses like this?

```
{
  "ipv6": true,
  "fixed-cidr-v6": "xxxx:xxxx:2:d0::216f:3000/124"
}
```

Or, is it just fine to use these (as if something like 192.168.0.x)?

```
{
  "ipv6": true,
  "fixed-cidr-v6": "2001:db8::c008/125"
}
```

Anyway I have tried the first one.

```
docker run -d --name ipv6test alpine ash -c "ping6 2606:4700:4700::1111"
```

I "docker inspect" for the IPv6 address. I make the NDP record:

```
ip -6 neigh add proxy xxxx:xxxx:2:d0::216f:3004 dev eth0
```

In this case, the container could communicate with the outside world.

Testing finished. I want to apply IPv6 to my project. It starts with docker-compose.

According to this page: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#ipv4_address-ipv6_address

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  app:
    image: nginx:alpine
    networks:
      app_net:
        ipv6_address: xxxx:xxxx:2:d0::216f:3010

networks:
  app_net:
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: "xxxx:xxxx:2:d0::216f:3000/124"
```

Inside the container, no connection could be made:

```
# ping6 2606:4700:4700::1111
PING 2606:4700:4700::1111 (2606:4700:4700::1111): 56 data bytes
ping6: sendto: Address not available
```

Have I missed anything?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Might be a little bit late, but this is the setup that worked for me on DigitalOcean:

1. Create `/etc/docker/daemon.json`:

```
{
    "ipv6": true,
    "fixed-cidr-v6": "<Your IPv6 address range start in DO console>/124"
}
```

2. `sudo systemctl restart docker`
3. Add to your `docker-compose.yml`:

```
    sysctls:
      - "net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=0"
```

Basically it seems the default is to disable IPv6 and we need to enable it in sysctl.

EDIT: Actually this allows the docker container to obtain an IPv6 address and perform IPv6 name resolution, but somehow it cannot send data (Network unreachable).

Although docker containers started with `docker` directly, which runs on the default `bridge` network, is able to access external IPv6 hosts, docker containers started by `docker-compose` runs in its dedicated network, so maybe one will need more routing work. My use case was actually limited (`socat` as IPv4 to IPv6 proxy) so I simply resorted to using the host network directly, with:

```
    network_mode: host
```

Answer (score 3):

My personal setup, that works.
It uses docker's internal default bridge instead of users supplied networking.

1. /etc/docker/daemon.json

```json
{
    "ipv6": true,
    "fixed-cidr-v6": "2a02:168:7a0e:11::/64"
}
```

2. docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: '3.3'

services:
  shell:
    networks:
      - bridge
    image: centos:8

networks:
  bridge:
    external: true
```

3. Testing

```sh
docker-compose run --rm shell
```

4. In container

```
[root@dfeb2fe7917d /]# ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
218917: eth0@if218918: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether 02:42:ac:11:00:02 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet 172.17.0.2/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 2a02:168:7a0e:11:0:242:ac11:2/64 scope global nodad 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::42:acff:fe11:2/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
[root@dfeb2fe7917d /]# ping6 -c 3 google.ch
PING google.ch(zrh04s15-in-x03.1e100.net (2a00:1450:400a:803::2003)) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from zrh04s15-in-x03.1e100.net (2a00:1450:400a:803::2003): icmp_seq=1 ttl=114 time=0.774 ms
64 bytes from zrh04s15-in-x03.1e100.net (2a00:1450:400a:803::2003): icmp_seq=2 ttl=114 time=1.12 ms
64 bytes from zrh04s15-in-x03.1e100.net (2a00:1450:400a:803::2003): icmp_seq=3 ttl=114 time=1.13 ms

--- google.ch ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 4ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.774/1.008/1.128/0.165 ms
```

Answer (score 2):

ipv6_address: xxxx:xxxx:2:d0::216f:3010
does not look like being in the same
subnet: xxxx:xxxx:2:d0::216f:3000/124

Try with something like xxxx:xxxx:2:d0::216f:300[0-f].